# Разбиение многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Мне нужно разбить многомерный массив, который появляется от апи, здесь же собирается в одно целое при помощи array_push(). Как установить им ключи, чтобы было проще брать данные из массива в массиве.

```
$Query_parameters = array();
array_push($Query_parameters, $Send, $Thank, $Call, $Contakt, $Store, $User, $Mobile, $Time);
foreach ($Query_parameters as $value => $i) {
                echo $value[1]; --> Здесь должно браться данные в массиве $Send, в который находится в $Query_parameters
            }
```

Пример массива:

```
Array (
 [0] => Вася
 [1] => 16
 [2] => школьник
)
Array (
 [0] => Петя
 [1] => 25
 [2] => программист
)
Array (
 [0] => Саня
 [1] => 55
 [2] => инженер
)
```

Comment: Что это за переменные? $Send, $Thank, $Call, $Contakt, $Store, $User, $Mobile, $Time

Comment: Это массивы, содержащие параметры, которые выдал апи. АПИ Метрики, если что.

Comment: Хорошо, а какие ключи вы хотите им установить? У вас же индексный массив, не понятно что где находится.

Comment: Ну например, массив $Send должен быть '0' => Array, и так далее

Comment: Если брать код c Foreach, который я написал выше, то он будет рабивать так: 14155733234062017-12-03, когда он должен вывести 14. Он выводит данные из всех массивов, когда надо, чтобы разбивались все по отдельности